# Can not import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, project, mysql-connector

I am new in Netbeans. Today I started a new java project connected with mysql. I added the jar file of msql to java connector to the libraries of the project.

When I am trying to import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection, it shows error and suggest me to change it or create a class named "Connection" in the package named "com.mysql.jdbc".
How to solve it?

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you aren't importing `java.sql.Connection`?

Comment: Hello @Mureinik , Thank you for your comment. I just following a youtube video. Where the youtuber use `import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;` So, I want to do exactly same as he do. But his program is running well. On the other hand, I am facing problem.

Comment: Can you share a complete snippet? Offhand, this doesn't look like the right way (or, at least, not the canonical way) of creating a JDBC connection.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4vpJJH2PZU&t=240s See the video after 20minute. May be it will be easy to understand .

Comment: What's the version and the name of the jar you added? Is it `mysql-connector-java5.1.47`?

Comment: It's 8.0.25 -@SimoneLungarella